# Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $m\geq 2$ and $T: V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^{n+1}=0$ and $T^{n}\neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $m\geq 2$  and $ T: V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^{n+1}=0$ and $T^{n}\neq 0$ for some $n\geq1$ .Then choose the correct statement(s):

$(1)$ $rank(T^n)\leq nullity(T^n)$

$(2)$ $rank(T^n)\leq nullity(T^{n+1})$

**Try:**

I found this case is possible if $n<m$ and took some examples for $(2)$ , found it true but I've no idea how to prove.
For (1) I'm not getting anything.

Comment: I found this case is possible if $n<m$ can you explain why

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan If $T^k=0$ for some $k$, then already $T^m=0$. It's a general fact about nilpotent endomorphisms of $m$-dimensional spaces. Thus, if $n\ge m$, it's impossible that $T^n\ne0$ and $T^{n+1}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

Let $y\in Range(T)$ $\implies y=T(x)$ for some $x\in V$, $T^{n+1}(x)=T^{n}(T(x))=0 \implies y \in Ker T^n.$

2. Let $y \in KerT^n \implies T^n(y)=0 \implies T^{n+1}(y)=T(T^n(y))=T(0)=0 \implies y \in KerT^{n+1}$

Answer (score 3):

$0=T^{n+1}(V)=T(T^n(V)) \implies rank(T^n)\le nullity (T)$.  But of course $nullity T\le nullity T^{n+1}$

So (2) is true.

Oh and (1) is true also...

For (1), see  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/400927)...

Comment: what about $(1)$..

Comment: Certainly $0 = T^{n+1}(V)$ implies the null space of $T^{n+1}$ is the full space $V$, so $nullity(T^{n+1}) =dim(V)$ which implies the conclusion that (2) is true. However, I cannot see how your alternative reasoning works: What relevance does $T(T^n(V))$ have in your argument, and how do you arrive at the "implies" sign?

Comment: @Michael the image of $T^n$, whose dimension is $rank(T^n)$, is a subspace of the null space of $T^{n+1}$...

Comment: The null space of $T^{n+1}$ is _everything_.  So what is the business of  $T(T^n(V))$? [In other words, your construction seems to be $2+2=4$ so $d/dx \sin(x) = \cos(x)$.  Both are true but I cannot follow the logical reasoning.]

Comment: @Michael  $T(T^n(V))=0$ says precisely that $T^n(V)\subset kerT$...  I see now that I skipped a step...  namely $kerT\subset kerT^2\subset \cdots kerT^{n+1}$...

Comment: I see your reasoning now, your last comment explains your original reasoning behind why you used $T(T^n(V))$.   Though it does seem a bit of overkill, since the null space of $T^{n+1}$ is the entire space so we are done (no subspaces can have larger dimension than the whole space).

Comment: (2) is *obviously* true. Your argument, with $\operatorname{nullity}T^n$ at the end proves (1).

Comment: @egreg  good insight...

Comment: @Michael  good point

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f=T^n$ is such that $f^2=0$. Thus $Im f \subseteq \ker f$ implies $rank(f) \le nullity(f) $, which is (1).